# GCP GroundingSource() 400 error Inline context must be specified

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run the grounding score API from GCP, where I am passing the context as a string to the API. But, I am getting the `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Inline context must be specified` error. I checked the request object and the dict-converted context of that is:

```
grounding_source._to_grounding_source_dict()
PyDev console: starting.
{'sources': [{'type': 'INLINE'}], 'inlineContext': 'The Pixel Tablet, offered by Google, comes in three elegant colors: Porcelain, Hazel, and Rose. Let’s delve into the details: Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $59912. Colors: Choose from the following stylish colors: Porcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup. Hazel: A warm and inviting color option. Rose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance3. Storage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants: 128GB UFS 3.1 storage 256GB UFS 3.1 storage42. In addition to its sleek design, the Pixel Tablet boasts impressive specs, including an expansive 10.95-inch LCD display with a resolution of 2560x1600 pixels, 8GB LPDDR5 RAM, and the powerful Google Tensor G2 processor. Its battery life allows for up to 12 hours of video streaming, and it charges via the included Charging Speaker Dock or a separate USB-C® charger'}
```

Here is the full code to reproduce the error:

```
from typing import Optional

import vertexai
from vertexai.language_models import (
    GroundingSource,
    TextGenerationModel,
    TextGenerationResponse,
)


def grounding(
    project_id: str, location: str = "",
    data_store_location: Optional[str] = None,
    data_store_id: Optional[str] = None) -> TextGenerationResponse:
    """Grounding example with a Large Language Model"""

    vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=location)

    # TODO developer - override these parameters as needed:
    parameters = {
        "temperature": 0.7,  # Temperature controls the degree of randomness in token selection.
        "max_output_tokens": 256,  # Token limit determines the maximum amount of text output.
        "top_p": 0.8,  # Tokens are selected from most probable to least until the sum of their probabilities equals the top_p value.
        "top_k": 40,  # A top_k of 1 means the selected token is the most probable among all tokens.
    }

    model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained("text-bison@002")
    source = "The Pixel Tablet, offered by Google, comes in three elegant colors: Porcelain, Hazel, and Rose. Let’s delve into the details: Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $59912. Colors: Choose from the following stylish colors: Porcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup. Hazel: A warm and inviting color option. Rose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance3. Storage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants: 128GB UFS 3.1 storage 256GB UFS 3.1 storage42. In addition to its sleek design, the Pixel Tablet boasts impressive specs, including an expansive 10.95-inch LCD display with a resolution of 2560x1600 pixels, 8GB LPDDR5 RAM, and the powerful Google Tensor G2 processor. Its battery life allows for up to 12 hours of video streaming, and it charges via the included Charging Speaker Dock or a separate USB-C® charger"
    if source is not None:
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.InlineContext(source)
    elif data_store_id and data_store_location:
        # Use Vertex AI Search data store
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.VertexAISearch(
            data_store_id=data_store_id, location=data_store_location
        )
    else:
        # Use Google Search for grounding (Private Preview)
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.WebSearch()

    response = model.predict(
        "What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?",
        grounding_source=grounding_source,
        **parameters,
    )
    print(f"Response from Model: {response.text}")
    print(f"Grounding Metadata: {response.grounding_metadata}")


grounding(project_id="selfcheck1")
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/grounding/ground-language-models#ground_the_text-bison_model)?

Comment: @kiranmathew In that link it uses `VertexAISearch` or `WebSearch` which is not what I need.

Comment: It seems like the error is generated from the if condition (if source is not None:). Is your code working fine when the source is None?

Comment: If you set `source=None`, that is not a grounding task anymore. It will be a generation task, where it works fine.